NextJS API route is not able to access search params
I have a simple NextJS app where I have a client component that calls an API route.
I am trying to access some search params in a route that I created but it is always returning null.
My client component is like so which calls my API on click of a button
export default function ClientComponent() {

  const getData = async ({
    secretId
  }) => {
    const url = new URL('/api/mydata', window.location.href)
    url.searchParams.set('secretId', secretId) // attaches the query param and this value is definitely there
    
    const response = await fetch(url)

    const data = await response.json()

    console.log("data:", data)
  }
  
  return (
    <button onClick={handleGetSecret}>
      Reveal secret
    </button>
  )
}

I then have a route app/api/mydata/route.tsx which handles the request
import { NextRequest } from "next/server"

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {

  const secretId = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get('secretId')

  console.log("secretId:", secretId)
  
  return Response.json({ message: 'hello', secretId })
}

but somehow secretId which I try get from the search params is always null.
I have tried converting this to a post endpoint to use the request body too but same thing happens. The value is always null
I have also tried calling this endpoint from Postman and the same thing happens. It seems NextJS isn't able to access search params in route files even though I tried to follow this here
Any idea what might be causing the value to be returning null even when I can see the search param in my URL when I print the object?
NextURL {
  [Symbol(NextURLInternal)]: {
    url: URL {
      href: 'http://localhost:3000/api/mydata?secretId=abc123',
      origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
      protocol: 'http:',
      username: '',
      password: '',
      host: 'localhost:3000',
      hostname: 'localhost',
      port: '3000',
      pathname: '/api/secrets',
      search: '?secretId=abc123',
      searchParams: URLSearchParams { 'secretId' => 'abc123' },
      hash: ''
    },
    options: { headers: [Object], nextConfig: undefined },
    basePath: '',
    domainLocale: undefined,
    defaultLocale: undefined,
    buildId: undefined,
    locale: undefined,
    trailingSlash: false
  }
}

You can see here a screenshot of my Postman request

and this is a cURL request I have tried
curl --location 'http://localhost:3000/api/mydata/?secretId=abc123'

